# Is is possible to populate a datatable using a Lambda expression(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a datatable. I am populating some values into that.
e.g.

```
DataTable dt =new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Col2",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Col3",typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Col4",typeof(bool));


for(int i=0;i< 10;i++)
dt.Rows.Add(i,"String"  + i.toString(),DateTime.Now,(i%2 == 0)?true:false);
```

There is nothing wrong in this program and gives me the expected output.

However, recently , I am learning Lambda and has done some basic knowledge.

With that I was trying to do the same thing as under

```
Enumerable.Range(0,9).Select(i = > 
{

    dt.Rows.Add(i,"String"  + i.toString(),DateTime.Now,(i%2 == 0)?true:false);
});
```

But I am unsuccessful.

Is my approach correct(Yes I know that I am getting compile time error; since not enough knowledge on the subject so far)?

Can we achieve this by the way I am doing is a big doubt(as I donot know.. just giving a shot).

If so , can some one please help me in this regard.

I am using C#3.0 and dotnet framework 3.5

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. Just remove the `{`curly braces`}` and the space in "`= >`".

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => dt.Rows.Add(i, 
    "String" + i.ToString(), DateTime.Now, (i%2 == 0) ? true : false));
```

Comment: Any other way of doing it using LINQ

Answer (score 2):

The Select method returns an enumerable with deferred execution.  To make the enumerable execute, you must enumerate it.  Also - dt.Rows.Add returns void, so it is an Action, not a Func and cannot be used in the Select call.

Instead of using Select, how about using

```
ToList<T>().ForEach<T>(Action<T>)
```

As in:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,9)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(i =>  
  {
    dt.Rows.Add(i,"String"  + i.ToString(), DateTime.Now, (i%2 == 0) );
  });
```